# I tried installing Python 3.7 on my WSL ubuntu 20.04 but it just won't install

Tags: apt, python, windows-subsystem-for-linux

This is the command I used:

```
sudo apt-get install python3.7
```

But I got:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'python3.7-2to3' for regex 'python3.7'
Note, selecting 'libpython3.7-stdlib' for regex 'python3.7'
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 91 not upgraded.
```

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu app are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and I solved it using the [deadsnakes PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Edeadsnakes/+archive/ubuntu/ppa).

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install python3.7
```